# Protractor config file to use both jasmine and cucumber specs

Tags: jasmine, protractor, cucumber

I have end to end tests written using jasmine and behavioural driven tests written using chai and cucumber. I have two configurations file to run these tests. How can I make use of single protractor config file to run specs of jasmine and cucumber ?

```
//cucumber.conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom', 
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.feature'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',

},
baseUrl: '',

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.steps.js'],  
    tags: [],                      
    strict: true,                  
    format: ["pretty"],            
    dryRun: false,                 
    compiler: []                   
  }

  //e2e.conf.js
  exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine2',    
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

      specs: ['test/e2e/e2e-spec.js'],
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox', 
    },
    baseUrl: '',
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
       showColors: true,
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a basic setup you can't because you need to provide for example the framework and you can't have 2 frameworks in 1 *default* configuration file.

What you can do is use a command line argument and a cli tool like [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) and do something like this. If you run protractor through for example a `npm script` you can do something like this

`npm run e2e -- --bdd`

```js
// the commmand line tool
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

// place you default config here, that should hold all the configs that are used with 
// Jsasmine and CucumberJS
const config = {
  baseUrl: '',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',

  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
};

// If you pass --bdd to your commandline it will use cucumberjs, default is jasmine 2
if (argv.bdd) {
  config.framework = 'custom';
  config.frameworkPath = require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework');
  config.specs = ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.feature'];
  config.cucumberOpts = {
    require: ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.steps.js'],
    tags: [],
    strict: true,
    format: ["pretty"],
    dryRun: false,
    compiler: []
  };
} else {
  config.framework = 'jasmine2';
  config.specs = ['test/e2e/e2e-spec.js'];
  config.jasmineNodeOpts = {
    showColors: true,
  };
}

exports.config = config;
```